# Conditional acceptance

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, europe

I just got a conditional admission from a highly prestigious master's programme in Europe but I have a question. What happens if I got conditionally accepted but I can't provide my diploma at a given time written in the letter? (because my graduation will be after the deadline). I already contacted with the university but it would be nice if you could share your experiences if you had something similar.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to ask them. In the best case we can give general, vague answers.

Answer (score 1):

Every such case is individual and depends on the rules set in place. Contact both universities, actually. Perhaps your current institution can assure the new one that the diploma is certain to be issued by some date. Perhaps the new institution will accept that. But it is up to them.

I doubt that they will be especially finicky about the rules, but no one can say but them. Keep all of your other options open until things are finalized.

Even a letter from a professor might assure them that all is well.

Comment: I already contacted my university but I will get the response tomorrow. I also contacted with some students from the same department where I applied to if they do know something about this or not but this will take at least a day for them to see and answer. I hope a document given by my current university would be OK.

Comment: Talking to students isn't going to get you anywhere. You need to correspond with whoever made the offer. Administration or some "hiring" PI.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking maybe if they had similar problems or they know someone who had been in my situation, they would know how things go. Actually I already contacted with the corresponding person but this will take some time as well.